# How to convert / migrate a Joomla 2.5 template into Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, templates, template-framework

I have a Joomla 2.5 template and I want to make it compatible with Joomla 3.x?

Are there any resources out there that I can use? I basically need to know what has changed, deprecated methods, common problems?

I am not looking for detailed descriptions, just some starting points (links).

Comment: Hello Amirali, actually, I am not that sure if this question is on topic or too broad... So other JSE members may decide. Truth is there are some special notes regarding making a Joomla 3 template or upgrading an older one... but yet the whole process can be long enough, constituting a tutorial like answer... Below I posted some links to resources for helping you with your research.

Comment: I reformulated the question and decided to keep it open. Thanks @all for trying to answer it.

Answer (score 5):

Some links that might be of help:

- [Template Considerations during Migration](https://docs.joomla.org/Template_Considerations_During_Migration)
- [Converting previous Joomla templates](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Converting_A_Previous_Joomla!_Version_Template)
- [Migrating a template from J1.5 to J3](https://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_a_Template_from_Joomla_1.5_to_3.x)
- [StackOverflow - converting a J2.5 to J3 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055707/convert-joomla-2-5-template-to-3-0)
- and you can probably find a lot more resources if you do a web search.

Answer (score 4):

The process of converting a Joomla 2.5 template into 3.4 is removing deprecated and removed functions.

It's more difficult if the template has older legacy functions from Joomla 1.6, and 1.7.

Here is a reference that could help
https://techjoomla.com/developers-blogs/joomla-development/joomla-30-conversion-changes-needed-when-converting-a-common-installable-package-for-joomla-15x-a-25x-to-joomla-30.html

Note: A template is just a specialized type of extension which is why I'm sharing an extension upgrade reference.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer. Don't bother.

You'll spend a lot more time attempting that than either finding a similar looking Joomla 3 template and customising it or just creating a new one yourself. Joomla 3 templates are now designed as responsive and have left behind many deprecated functions from 2.5.

Comment: Actually that is not always true. I have done a lot of Joomla 2.5.28 to Joomla 3.4.5 migrations in less than 30 mins. It all depends on the complexity of the template and any underlying PHP Framework it does or doesnt use.

Comment: How please give me some guidance?

Comment: @PhilTaylor, if you have some tips or instructions for template migration, please share!